# How to setup Sylius to use Redis as Cache Backend

Tags: symfony, caching, redis, sylius

According the https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineCacheBundle#cache-providers there are several parameters necessary to use redis instead of file_system as cache backend.

In the main configuration file of Sylius, there is only one area to put cache settings:

app/config/parameters.yml

```
sylius.cache:
    type: redis (was file_system)
```

Where to put the rest?

- connection_id - Redis connection service id
- host          - redis host
- port          - redis port

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax:

```
sylius.cache:
    type: redis
    namespace: sylius
    redis:
        host: localhost
        port: 6379
        database: 10
```

Sylius then creates a doctrine cache provider with this configuration.

Comment: Where would this go in v1.3? The configuration files are different, and `parameters.yaml` is gone. I'm guessing `config/packages/_sylius.yaml`?